# C# files array gridview dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wanting to create a webpage for my company that will list all PDF documents associated with a client. I have all the PDF's in the same folder, and the excel spreadsheet is in this folder as well. I currently have a gridview that populates the data from the excel sheet, so, that is working fine. It puts it into a table for view on the page. Now, lets say the excel spreedsheet has 2 columns (Company and Owner):

> Companies:
>   1) ACME,
>   2) Slaters,
>   3) MotoUSA
>
> Owners:
>   1)John,
>   2) Mike,
>   3) John

So, John is the owner of company #1 and #3 & Mike is owner of #2

I have PDF to associate with all these companies. They have a naming scheme of:

> ACME - document1.pdf
>   ACME - document2.pdf
>   Slaters - document1.pdf
>   MotoUSA - document1.pdf
>   MotoUSA - document2.pdf
>   MotoUSA - document3.pdf
>   MotoUSA - document4.pdf

So every PDF will start off with the exact same company name and same spelling. What I am looking for is to have the gridview show the table of just the company name and owner, but allow the user to click on the company name and it dropdown to show only the PDF associated with that company.

I am sure I will need an array for this and some editing of my gridview.

Any assistance would be appreciated, and please let me know if I left anything out of this description.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a link for the CompanyName and write some javascript to open a popup,
and give the documents links in the popup accorrding to company name.

If you can share your code that would help people to write better answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

We link our internal site to active directory and use the credentialing provided through the browser to determine who has access to what.

As far as getting the data into a datagrid, it depends on your target framework.  However, if you are current, then Linq and datagrids were meant for each other.

> I am sure I will need an array for this and some editing of my gridview.

Linq returns an IEnumerable and There's probably some great information on google for getting the information from an IEnumerable to populate a datagrid control.

As mentioned before, it might be handy to have a little more code to go on as you develop this solution further.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of all the files in your directory using :

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
```

Then you fetch all the names from these filenames and format the filename into a class with filename and companyname.

```
List<CompanyFile> companyFiles = new List<CompanyFile>();
foreach(string filename in fileEntries)
{
    string[] filenameInfo = filename.Split(" - ");
    companyFiles.Add(new CompanyFile{
         CompanyName=filenameInfo[0],
         Filename=filenameInfo[1],
         OriginalFilename=filename
    });
}
```

So now that you have a list of companyFiles you can group them by companyname so the result will be a list of companies, each with a list of their files.

```
List<Company> companies = (from c in companyFiles
                           group c by c.CompanyName into g
                           select new Company { CompanyName=g.Key, FileNames=g }).ToList();
```

These are the class you'll need to get this example working:

```
class CompanyFile{
     public string CompanyName {get;set;}
     public string Filename {get;set;}
     public string OriginalFilename {get;set;}
}

class Company{
     public string CompanyName {get;set;}
     public List<string> FileNames {get;set;}
}
```

Once you got the `companies` list you can use this to search for the owner of the company and list all the files of the specific company.

**Note:** I didn't have time to compile this (just wrote it in this editor). Let me know if it works out for you.